# necesito un boton eliminar en una tabla donde agrego filas

Tags: php, javascript

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var names = ["pregunta[]", "descripcion[]", "puntaje[]"];
        function add(tableID) {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
            var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

            for (var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
                var newentry = document.createElement('textarea');
                newentry.name = names[i];
                newentry.type = "text";
                newcell.appendChild(newentry);
            }
        }
    </script>
    
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="enviar.php">
    <table id="table">
    <tr><th>pregunta</th><th>descripcion</th><th>puntaje</th></tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td><textarea name = "pregunta[]"></textarea></td>
    <td><textarea name = "descripcion[]"></textarea></td>
    <td><textarea name = "puntaje[]"></textarea></td>
    <tr>
  
    </table>
    <input type ="button" value="add entry" onclick="add('table')"/>
    <input type ="submit" id="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

hola, yo no tengo mucho conocimiento sobre js, pero encontre este codigo y lo adapte un poco a lo que queria, que es tener una tabla donde pueda agregar filas y tambien ingresar cualquier texto o numero para luego mostrarlo en otra pagina, pero no como hacer que funcione un boton remover, para poder eliminar alguna de las filas generadas.

Answer (score 0):

para eliminar la última fila de una tabla puedes usar una función como:

```
const deleteLastRow = (table) => {
  if (!!table) {
    const lastRowIdx = table.rows.length - 1;
    table.deleteRow(lastRowIdx);
  }
}
```

Luego cada vez que se presione el botón para eliminar la última fila, llama a esta función y pásale como parámetro la tabla en sí:

```
document.getElementById('my-delete-button-id').addEventListener('click', (e) => 
 {
   deleteLastRow(document.getElementById('table'))
 })
```

Recuerda crear el botón en el HTML:

```
<input type ="button" id="my-delete-button-id" value="delete last entry" />
```

Comment: tu primer comentario en cuanto al "const deleteLastRow" donde lo ubico ... en mi codigo dentro de la funcion del tu segundo comentario???